# How to add two Ints in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, int

I am trying to make an application that allows you to save a number in UserDefaults and then add onto that number later on. Right now, I keep getting the error:

> 'Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands'

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var totalHoursInt = 0
    var typeHoursInt = 0
    var savedHours = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var totalHours: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var typeHours: UITextField!

    @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: Any) {
        totalHours.text = typeHours.text!
        UserDefaults.standard.set(typeHours.text, forKey: "savedHours")
        typeHours.text = ""

        var totalHoursInt = Int(totalHours.text!)
        var typeHoursInt = Int(typeHours.text!)

        print(totalHoursInt + typeHoursInt)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedHours") as? String {
            totalHours.text = x
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Those are not two `Ints`, are two `Int?'s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Int()` with a String argument doesn’t return an Int value but an Int Optional. This is because the String to Int conversion could fail in which case the conversion returns nil. And the `+` operator simply isn’t defined for optionals.

To solve your problem you will need to make sure the returned values aren in-nil, using a construct like this:

```
if let totalHours = totalHoursInt, let typeHours = typeHoursInt {
    print(totalHours + typeHours)
}
```

`if let ...` assigns a value only if the right side is non-nil so the variables are converted from optionals to non-optionals. (You’re using that in `viewDidAppear`.) After that, the `+` operator will work.